# Can Gibbs law (& combined first and second law of thermodynamics) be used only for a system (and not a control volume ie flow process)?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was going through a problem related to flow through isentropic nozzle and I realized that the $v\mathrm{d}p$ term in the Gibbs laws, when applied to a nozzle, doesn't turn zero.

$\mathrm{d}h=T\mathrm{d}s+V\mathrm{d}p$ (note: h,T,V,and P are all static quantity)

$V\mathrm{d}p$ is usually called *isentropic shaft work*, and there is *no isentropic shaft work when considering a flow through a nozzle*. But if we are considering static quantities (static pressure, temperature etc) then *there is a static pressure drop between the inlet and outlet of the nozzle* and so the $V\mathrm{d}P$ term cannot be zero, (and so this would mean there is shaft work in nozzle). So I am wondering if the Gibbs law & combined first and second law of thermodynamics can be used only for a system and not to a flow process (and also what the $V\mathrm{d}P$ work mean in the closed syste & in the  equation $\mathrm{d}h=T\mathrm{d}s+V\mathrm{d}p$).

[I have applied the SFEE to the nozzle where I have taken the work ,W, (and heat) to be zero and that  the total enthalpy remains constant throughout an isentropic nozzle, (given no change in potential energy).]

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the differential of h is Tds+Vdp, not Tds-Vdp.

Secondly, the term Vdp only sometimes represents shaft work, not always.

Thirdly, for a nozzle, one must include not only the change in enthalpy but also the change in kinetic energy of the flowing stream.  So, for an isentropic nozzle (involving no shaft work), the SFEE reduces to:$$\Delta(h+\frac{1}{2}u^2)=0$$or $$dh+udu=Vdp+udu=0$$
I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the correction of the equation!. So what does VdP represent when applied to a closed system (say a 'closed' element of fluid going through a nozzle). Does it still represent work?. Also, can the equation dh=TdS+VdP be applied to an open system?

Comment: VdP doesn't have to have any particular physical interpretation when applied to a system like a nozzle.  It is just the differential change in enthalpy at constant entropy. It follows from dU=TdS-PdV and the definition of enthalpy.  The equation dh=TdS+VdP applies to a single phase not undergoing a chemical reaction.

Comment: @ChetMillet "The equation dh=TdS+VdP applies to a single phase not undergoing a chemical reaction." Is the single phase considered as undergoing flow OR is it a closed single phase system?

Comment: The equation dh=TdS+VdP is a physical property relation of the fluid (gas or liquid), and is independent of the process.

Answer (score 0):

**Local equilibrium**

If the **assumption of local equilibrium** (usually exploited to use thermodynamics in fluid mechanics), you can use thermodynamic relations for every fluid particle.

**Solution of the problem**

It seems to me that you did it right. Let's revisit the problem using integral equations for a fluid in a control volume:

- mass:
  $\dfrac{d}{dt}\displaystyle \int_V \rho + \oint_S \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0$
- momentum (not needed here): ...
- total energy:
  $\dfrac{d}{dt}\displaystyle \int_V \rho e^t + \oint_S \rho e^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \int_V \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \int_V (-p\mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{s}_n) \cdot \mathbf{u} - \oint_S \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}$

to be simplified using some assumptions, basically

- steady flow $\frac{d}{dt} \equiv 0$;
- no volume force $\mathbf{g} = \mathbf{0}$;
- negligible viscous stress $\mathbf{s}_n = 0$, negligible heat transfer $\mathbf{q} = 0$, without shock waves and thus isentropic conditions *(don't make me prove it here. If needed, look for balance equation for entropy, or Clausius-Duhem condition)*;
- perfect gas law $P = \rho R T$; for isentropic conditions you get $\dfrac{P}{\rho^\gamma} = const$;
- uniform properties on each section of the nozzle.

The **simplified equations** read

- mass:

  $\oint_S \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0 \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \rho_1 A_1 V_1 = \rho_2 A_2 V_2$
- total energy, introducing the definition of total enthalpy $h^t = e^t + \frac{P}{\rho} =\dfrac{1}{2}|\mathbf{u}^2| + e + \frac{P}{\rho}$:

  $\oint_S \rho h^t \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0 \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \rho_1 A_1 V_1 h^t_1 = \rho_2 A_2 V_2 h^t_2 \qquad \rightarrow \qquad h^t_1 = h^t_2$

and you can use them along with the condition for isentropic transformations $P_1/\rho_1^\gamma = P_2/\rho_2^\gamma$ and the constitutive equation for perfect gases.

**Differential form of quasi-1D isentropic equations**

Since mass flux is constant through the sections of the nozzle, you can write

$0 = d \dot{m} := \rho A V + \rho dA V + \rho A dV$.

Since $h^t$ is constant, you can use one of the equivalent forms of the following equation

$0 = d h^t = V dV + dh = V dV + de + d\left(\dfrac{P}{\rho}\right) = V dV + \underbrace{de - \left(\dfrac{P}{\rho^2}\right)d\rho}_{= de + P dv = Tds \quad  (1^{st} Pr.)} + \dfrac{dP}{\rho} = VdV + Tds + v dP$.

For isentropic flows, where $ds=0$, you get

$VdV + v dP = 0$.